# Отсутствие двоеточия при однородных членах

Tags: пунктуация

Доносились звуки шум, треск и гул.

Байроном были написаны поэмы "Паломничество Чайльд-Гарольда", "Мазепа", "Дон Жуан".

Обязательна ли в предыдущих предложениях постановка двоеточия после обобщающего слова?

Answer (score 1):

*Доносились (различные) **звуки**: шум, треск и гул.*

Звуки — обобщающее слово (не приложение), поэтому двоеточие ставится в обязательном порядке.

*Байроном были написаны **поэмы** "Паломничество Чайльд-Гарольда", "Мазепа", "Дон Жуан.*

Двоеточие обычно не ставится, так как поэмы — это приложение. При наличии паузы постановка двоеточия допускается.

Сравнить: *Байроном были написаны **следующие поэмы**: "Паломничество Чайльд-Гарольда", "Мазепа", "Дон Жуан.*  Распространенное приложение в роли обобщающего слова.

Обязательная постановка двоеточия связана с наличием  слова *следующие*, так как требуется раскрытие его содержания.

Comment: Как вы определили, что "поэма" является приложением, а "звуки" не являются?

Comment: Легко. (Хотела сначала включить эту информацию в ответ, но потом передумала). Я рассматриваю сочетания. Поэма "Дон Жуан", здесь поэма - приложение. Звук шум. Такого сочетания нет, поэтому звук не является приложением (в грамматическом плане), хотя в физике шум - это звук с определенной характеристикой.

Comment: Может быть "Дон Жуан" — приложение? Приложение ведь является определением и отвечает на вопрос какой(какая)?

Comment: Может быть.  Рассмотрим пример: кошка Мурка и девочка Маша.  Говорят, что Мурка - это приложение, а Маша - определяемое существительное (из уважения к Маше, вероятно). Хотя грамматически это должно быть одно и то же. Мне больше нравится грамматический подход.  Кстати, на постановку двоеточия ваше замечание никак не влияет.

Comment: В таком случае приложениями не являются слова шум, треск и гул, а не слово звук. Просто потому что данные сочетания не встречаются? Отчего эти звуки не могут быть приложениями? Звуки какие? Шум, треск и гул.

Comment: Нужно рассматривать возможные сочетания слов. Слово звук не образует грамматические словосочетания со словами шум, треск, гул. Мы не можем сказать:  звук шум, звук треск. А функция приложения определяется только в словосочетании.  Примеры словосочетаний: гора Казбек, гриб подосиновик, кузнец Архип, газета "Правда".  На первом месте приложение, на втором - определяемое существительное. Если приложение поставить на второе место, то написание будет дефисным: Казбек-гора, полынь-трава. Обычно такие сочетания образуют слова, связанные отношениями род+ вид или нар. + собств.

Comment: А одного вопроса какой? недостаточно, если нет словосочетания.  Мы можем сказать: Существуют разные (какие?) звуки: шум, треск и гул. Но это будет обобщающее слово, а не приложение, хотя по смыслу звук (какой?). Но нет словосочетания - значит, нет приложения.

Comment: А что такое "грамматическое словосочетание"? Ведь "звук" и "шум" также вступают в родо-видовые отношения.

Comment: Родо-видовые отношения встречаются часто, что нельзя сказать о словосочетаниях.  Обычно здесь речь идет о научной классификации в биологии, химии и т.д : газ водород, бабочка белянка, трава полынь. Сочетаемость легко проверить на слух. Мы говорим: столовая - это комната, где обедают.  В квартире три комнаты: спальня, детская, гостиная.Но мы не можем сказать "комната спальня". Или можем?

Answer (score 0):

Всё просто: если есть кавычки, то двоеточие не обязательно (но возможно, если есть пауза).

Ещё можно поменять на родительный, чтобы не было двоеточия:
*Доносились звуки шума, треска и гула.*